# How to play a video only for given time intervals in react-native-video

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-video

I am trying to make a video trimming component in react native. I have implemented a Trimmer component with react-native-animated. you can see it in action in the following gif:

[image]

the next step for me to create an illusion in this UI to give feedback to user in which time interval will be played. This step will reduce video post processing time a lot because real video trimming will be triggered by pressing another button.

So in order for me to create such illusion on UI level, i need to command to react-native-video just to play the video for given intervals and replay the video in auto-loop.

I have read their documentations but i believe there is no prop just for this purpose, so i need help on creating such logic,

any help will be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with `seek` and `onProgress`.

```
const [selection,setSelection] = useState({start:0,end:10});

<Video
    ref={videoRef}
    onProgress={({currentTime}) => {
        if(currentTime >= selection.end){
            videoRef.current?.seek(selection.start);
        }
    }}
/>
```

You are already storing your selected start and end time in a some kind of state so you just need to listen to the current time with [`onProgress`](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#onprogress) event prop. When the current time reaches to the selected end time you can call the [`seek`](https://github.com/react-native-video/react-native-video/blob/master/API.md#seek) method and pass the selected start time so the video goes back to the selected start position and keep playing from there until it reaches the selected end time again.

The logic can be altered based on how you choose to play the video.